# Google Apps Script Gmail getPlainBody Line Breaks

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

With the Google Apps Script Gmail library, when I use the function `GmailMessage.getPlainBody()`, the API seems to take what used to be one paragraph and break it up into multiple, potentially by using a character limit. For instance, a paragraph of my email reads:

```
From the link you sent me, I gleaned that Gmail refers to their secure email as confidential.
```

But when I call this function on the email, it becomes:

```
From the link you sent me, I gleaned that Gmail refers to their
secure email as confidential.
```

And, when I split the email text on a new line delimitor and do a bit of cleanup to create an array with my output, I end up with:

```
['From the link you sent me, I gleaned that Gmail refers to their', 'secure email as confidential.']
```

I viewed [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5icwkz/how_do_you_create_multiple_paragraphs_from_one/), which seemed to deal with the similar problem. But, I tried the resolution suggested by the person who posed the question:

```
body =  message.getPlainBody().replace(/\r\n\r\n/gm,'aaaLINEBREAKERaaa').replace(/\r\n/gm,' ').replace(/aaaLINEBREAKERaaa/gm, '\r\r').replace(/  /gm,' ')
```

And it didn't quite give me what I need. Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, do you have a suggested workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I proposed a workaround I had used. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Looks great! Would still appreciate an alternative if anyone else has ideas, but this will work for now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. In that case, I used a workaround.

When I checked the email, I noticed that the HTML body is included in the message body and the HTML body has the original paragraph, and I used this situation. So, in this workaround, the original text is retrieved from the HTML body and the HTML is converted to a text. By this, the original paragraph is obtained. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This script uses Drive API for converting HTML to text. So [pelase enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
var message =  // Here, please use your "message".

var html = message.getBody();
var id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, Utilities.newBlob(html, MimeType.HTML)).id;
var text = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText(); // or DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText().trim();
DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
console.log(text)
```

#### References:

- [getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getbody)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

Comment: This is an interesting proposal--thank you! I will have a chance to test it out later :)

Comment: I think this will do what I need--thank you!!

Comment: @Lle.4 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.